# In primeng Datatable custom filter not working

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a datatable with column Org . Distinct list of orgs are in an array. How to add this list in the column filter dropdown box. When i try to add the options with the list , drop down displays with no value.can someone please  let me know how to add dynamic values in the dropdown?

```
<p-column  field="org" header ="Org" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="equals">
        <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
          <p-dropdown [options]="orgGroupList" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"  styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
      </p-column>


this.orgGroupList = 2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after including   appendTo="body" in the drop down tag

```
<ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
          <p-dropdown [options]="orgs" [(ngModel)]="selectedOrg" appendTo="body" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"  (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
        </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

`[options]` should be array of `SelectItem` interface objects. Each item should include label and value properties:

```
{label: 'MyDisplayValue', value: 1}
```

In your code you pass array of integers (`this.orgGroupList = 2,3,4,5,6,7`) as `[options]` input. Change it to array of `SelectItem` interface objects.

For reference you can see official example source code at: 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter

Comment: i assume your code is `this.orgGroupList = [2,3,4,5,6,7]`